# Will java streams sum values of a ConcurrentHashMap in an consistent manner?

Tags: java, java-stream, concurrenthashmap

I have a concurrentHashMap instance that some threads add entries to. The values are integers.

Simultaneously, other threads wish to retrieve the sum of all the values in the map. I wish that these threads see a consistent value. However, it doesn't need to be such that they always see the latest value.

Is the following code thread safe?

```
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap;

public class MyClass {
    private Map<Integer, Integer> values = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

    public void addValue(Integer key, int value){
        values.put(key, value);
    }

    public long sumOfValues(){
        return values
                .values()
                .stream()
                .mapToInt(Integer::intValue)
                .sum();
    }
}
```

Will the sum operation be calculated on a consistent set of values?

When the sum operation is happening, will calls to put() be blocked?

Of course I could synchronize the access myself, and even split the read and write locks to allow for concurrent read access and synchronized write access, but I am curious if its necessary when using concurrentHashMap as the collection implementation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html) says about `ConcurrentHashMap`'s `keySet()` and `entrySet()`: *The view's iterators and spliterators are weakly consistent.*

Weakly consistent [characterized as](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html#Weakly)

- they may proceed concurrently with other operations
- they will never throw ConcurrentModificationException
- they are guaranteed to traverse elements as they existed upon construction exactly once, and may (but are not guaranteed to) reflect any modifications subsequent to construction.

So...

> Is the following code thread safe?

Yes, in the narrow sense of absent ConcurrentModificationException or internal inconsistencies of the HashMap.

> Will the sum operation be calculated on a consistent set of values?

on a weakly consistent set

> When the sum operation is happening, will calls to put() be blocked?

No

Answer (score 1):

The point of `ConcurrentHashMap` is that the entries are as independent from one another as possible. There isn't a consistent view of the whole map. Indeed, even `size` doesn't return a very useful value.

Comment: So I should probably use a read and write lock to guarantee consistent values. I can memoize the sum in the write addValue also I guess.

Comment: @ThatDataGuy Yup. You could use an `AtomicInteger` to keep the total, but the update would be complicated and wouldn't be much/any advantage anyway.

Comment: @ThatDataGuy this raises the question what kind of consistency do you expect in the presence of concurrent updates. The result is outdated as soon as you receive it.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to query the sum concurrently, one solution is to write a wrapper class which maintains both the map's state and the sum, using a `LongAdder` to atomically maintain the sum.

```java
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentMap;
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.LongAdder;

public class MapSum {
    private final ConcurrentMap<Integer, Integer> map = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
    private final LongAdder sum = new LongAdder();

    public Integer get(Integer k) {
        return map.get(k);
    }

    public Integer put(Integer k, Integer v) {
        Integer[] out = new Integer[1];
        map.compute(k, (_k, old) -> {
            out[0] = old;
            // cast to long to avoid overflow
            sum.add((long) v - (old != null ? old : 0));
            return v;
        });
        return out[0];
    }

    public Integer remove(Integer k) {
        Integer[] out = new Integer[1];
        map.compute(k, (_k, old) -> {
            out[0] = old;
            // cast to long to avoid overflow; -Integer.MIN_VALUE == Integer.MIN_VALUE
            if(old != null) { sum.add(- (long) old); }
            return null;
        });
        return out[0];
    }

    public long sum() {
        return sum.sum();
    }
}
```

This has the added benefit of querying the sum in O(1) instead of O(*n*) time. You can add more `Map` methods if you like, and even implement `Map<Integer, Integer>` - just be careful to maintain the sum when you change the map's contents in any way.

Comment: This doesn’t guaranty consistency; a `remove` call still could subtract a value the concurrent `put` call has not added yet, resulting in a sum that conceptually never existed.

Comment: Very good point! I've edited it to use the `compute` method, which should update `sum` while the lock for that key is still held. Hopefully that fixes the problem.